# Safely append boost filesystem path, detect upwards references

Tags: c++, boost, path

I would like to have a best prectice for this subject. I have to do some path magic prior to actually doing something.

```
using namespace boost::filesystem;
path p = "apple"; // apple 
p /= "pear";      // apple/pear
p /= "..";        // apple/pear/..                      // apple
p /= "chicken";   // apple/pear/../chicken              // apple/chichken
p /= "..";        // apple/pear/../chicken/..           // apple
p /= "..";        // apple/pear/../chicken/../..        // .
p /= "..";        // apple/pear/../chicken/../../..     // ..
p /= "cow";       // apple/pear/../chicken/../../../cow // ../cow
path s = "\\tmp\\file857463.tmp"; // s.is_relative() is true on windows
```

In every line after the first `//` you can see what I get when I print it. After the second `//` you can see what I would like to see (if differs)

What intermediate step can/should I do if I would like to see this behavior, considering that I surely do not want to touch the filesystem. After the final form appears I would like to test that the reference points inside the current directory or not (still without accessing the FS).

I would like to detect upwards jumps like `\` (windows) or `\\` (windows) or `/` on Linux. Quote from manual: **On Windows, path("/foo").is_absolute() returns false**. Which is IMHO very scientific, but useless. The main goal for me is to prevent upwards references without accessing characters by hand and without boost accessing the FS. (If I have to touch any characters manually I rather write my own path utility all together.)

I failed to find a robust concept for detecting drive root references. I tried boost documentation and Google too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use canonical: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical

Comment: Overview: Converts p, which must exist, to an absolute path that has no symbolic link, dot, or dot-dot elements. I mentioned mutiple times that I do not want to touch the actual FS.

Comment: In what way it touches FS? What do you mean by "not touching FS"? And why -1 for someone who tried to help? Do you even know it has different purpose?

Comment: You may use canonical with function from answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167550/527807

Comment: How is it ensures that the path has no symbolic links without touching the FS?