# how to create a relative path in linux OS, using C++ boost or std

Tags: c++, linux

Such as the title, how to do it. 
And what is the difference between the usage of making a absolute path and making a relative path.
Who can gave me a Sample code？
PS：my environment is centos

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167382/boostfilesystem-get-relative-path

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What are your inputs?  A relative path is just one that doesn't start with a `/` slash, e.g. `if (std::ifstream in("subdir/file.in"))`.  Absolute paths do start with a `/`.  What's your actual difficulty?  Where's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `boost::filesystem::create_directory` to create relative path or absolute path. My codes:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //create relative path
    const string reletive_path("./tmp");
    if(! boost::filesystem::exists(reletive_path))
        boost::filesystem::create_directory(reletive_path);

    //create absolute path
    const string abs_path("/tmp");
    if(! boost::filesystem::exists(abs_path))
        boost::filesystem::create_directory(abs_path);
    return 0;
 }
```

Whether creating a relative or a absolute depend on what param you give. For example, if you give `/tmp`, it will create a absolute, and `./tmp` will create a relative. I hope this can help you.